# 'nothing provides' message installing httpd

Tags: apache, yum, centos8, dnf

[Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbGSY.png)

error trying to install httpd

I tried using yum and dnf but the error was the same. Also tried using --nobest but "conflicting request" message appeared. I have the same problem trying to install mariadb-server.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https:/meta.stackoverflow.cm/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: Oops, how did that link get mangled without notice... [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)